# Can VM transport bypass broker authentication in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, jaas

Can VM transport bypass broker authentication in ActiveMQ? Why would the broker want to authenticate connections coming from within the VM?

I'm using JAAS authentication through LDAP and I don't think admins will create a PROD account for me just so my VM transport can connect to broker (since such account can be used to log in to the App too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, if your broker is secured then the VM Transport is not the way around this.  The Transport simply avoid writing data to a TCP or other IO stream but it doesn't circumvent the protections put in place by your broker configuration.

Comment: Thanks. I have to figure a away around this issue then.